# Git hub actions minutes not reset on first day of the month after purchasing

Tags: github-actions

I used the free default GitHub Actions minutes until recently. During that time period, the time limit for GitHub Actions would reset every first day of the month. However, after purchasing a package, the time limit no longer resets on the first day of the month.

What could be the reason for this change and how resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a spending limit, then the next GitHub action time reset date will be the date after one month from the spending limit set date.

Assume the spending limit set date is 2023/08/03 then the next action time reset date will be 2023/09/03